# File path=new File(".") ? java

Tags: file, io

- `File path=new File(".")` ? What does this code line do ?
- `File path=new File(args[0])` Does it gives absolute or relative path to the file with name given in `args[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your first line will create a Java File object which will point to the current directory i.e. the directory you started your Java program from. You can call `isDirectory()` on it and you should get true. Read the [Java 7 javadocs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).
- your second line will create a Java File object which will point to `args[0]`. It does not verify that the file exists or is readable or writable. This will be checked when you start trying to work with the file.

You can determine the absolute path of a File object using [method getAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()).